# New home, shower causes this leak

Tags: plumbing

We just bought a house two days ago and when someone took a shower, this just happened:

[video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnsEucAtFS_Slok9UNaXL_iNNgEclg)

It didn’t happen yesterday when I took a shower and doesn’t happen from running the kitchen sink or anything.   I was thinking maybe one difference is that it rained? But it’s on sewer, not a septic tank or anything so I’m confused.

Any ideas? Where do I even begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a sign of possibly a partially clogged drain or plugged vent. Your home came with a warranty, exercise it immediately, what you see should not happen. My guess is that repair should be the responsibility of the selling party. I am not party of the sales contract etc so I can only make a guess. Talk to your real estate agent and see what they have to say. You may have to talk to a legal professional. Assuming you  had the home inspected what did the inspector say. I am not a plumber but I do not think that would make code and a hose from a faucet in the pipe is that leaking as well. If the pressure system fails that could suck sewage into the potable water system.